# React js with Laravel (5.1): Removal of the URL hash causes laravel router to kick in and fail

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I have set up a simple app for now using ReactJS for the frontend and Laravel(5.1) for the backend.

All is OK but I woudl like to make the URLS look normal, as in the removal of the '/#' from the URL.

So

```
   example.co.uk/#/about
```

becomes

```
   example.co.uk/about
```

This is not an issue as I achieve this, but when I do it activate it, then the  Laravel routing kicks in and flags a route error.

Is it possible to prevent Laravel form activating / doing this so that ReactJS takes over and works.

If so it would also be nice, so that if a Laravel route is set / wanted then it does use that one.

EG: These are ReactJS routes that would have used the '/#'

```
   example.co.uk/about
   example.co.uk/details
   example.co.uk/listings
```

Then if I got to the following URL's then they are controlled by Laravel's routing?

```
   example.co.uk/api/...
   example.co.uk/admin/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a **catch-all** route that will execute the same main controller action regardless the URL. Add the following to your **routes.php**

```
Route::get('{path?}', 'Controller@action')->where('path', '.*');
```

This way all URLs will go to **Controller@action**, that should display the base view for your application - the one that runs the ReactJS application.

Comment: Great thanks for this.  So for a laravel controlled route, say Route::get('admin'... , where i want laravel to take control I have simply added this before the above route and it seems to work. let me know if incorrect but so far thanks.